# How to bring back parameters documentation popup in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts, intellisense

[image: Parameters documentation popup example]

This parameters documentation popup appears automatically whenever you type in the opening parenthesis of a method call.

Note that the popup displays documentation specific to the current parameter.

The popup also shows whenever you type in a comma between parameters.

So, when I want the documentation back, I usually erase and retype the comma before the parameter for which I want the doc. I've done that for years, but I realize now that there might be a better way to do this (read: shortcut key).

Therefore my question is : how do you bring back that parameters documentation popup?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual editor command to bring up parameter info is `Edit.ParameterInfo`.  The default key binding in C# for that command is <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Space</kbd>.

Note though this will only bring up parameter info.  If you wanted instead raw intellisense you'd need to use <kbd>Ctrl+Space</kbd>.