# How to bring back parameters documentation popup in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, parameters, tooltip

I would like to make this appear when I want to in SQL Server.

[image]

Is there a keyboard shortcut for it ? I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343431/how-to-bring-back-parameters-documentation-popup-in-visual-studio) for the one in Visual Studio where you pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: SQL 2005 does not have intellisense unless you opt for sql prompt some redgate tool

Answer (score 0):

install sql prompt software for that to use like this popup in sql-2005.